# iterating through a function's sub functions python

Tags: python, function

The goal is to try and access any function's sub functions. I've looked around and I'm not too sure there is a way to do it. When I've tried using

```
functions = [name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isfunction)]
```

which returns the functions in some module (in the above `__name__==__main__`). When I have used that method, it doesn't return any sub functions. However I'd like to access sub functions that look something like

```
def f(x):
    def y(x):
        return x += 3
    def z(x):
        return x**2 - 1
    x += y(x)
    x += z(x)
    return x
```

So it seems to me like there should be some way to access them with  a magic method of `f` or some attribute of `f`. I have a hard time believing that those sub functions aren't stored as some attribute of `f`, but I have no idea.

In the end, what I need to do is to iterate through the sub functions of some function, so I thought the solution would look something like

```
for subfunc in f.__method_that_returns_subfuncs__():
    if 'my_string' == subfunc.__name__:
        out = subfunc(args)
```

I just need to be able to compare a string to a subfunction name then call that subfunction.

Thanks

Comment: The functions are simply bound to local variables like anything you define inside `f`. There's nothing special about the fact that they are functions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit list of functions to iterate over. You need to define it yourself. Simply functions can be assigned directly to a list by defining them with lambda expressions; more complex functions will need to be defined first, then added. Examples of each:

```
def f(x):
    funcs = []

    def y(x):
        return x += 3
    f.append(y)

    f.append(lambda x: x**2 - 1)

    for func in funcs:
        x = func(x)
    
    
    return x
```

If you care about the name, you can access it via the `function` object's `__name__` attribute.

```
for func in funcs:
   if func.__name__ == "some_func":
       x = func(x)
```